# What is a good word for a tutor-student?

Tags: single-word-requests

After asking [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2645/1685) on [MathEducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), I was struck by the absolute awkwardness of not having a word to refer to the student of a tutor. As you will notice, the question contains in its title the awkward phrase "tutor-student;" I would like to find a suitable replacement for that word in my day-to-day use [as I am a tutor!].

Question in short: **What is the single-word equivalent for "tutor-student"?**

Comment: I probably could have used the "mathematics" tag....I didn't because even though it applies to myself in the sense of mathematics, it really is a bigger question than just math-tutoring specifically

Comment: You mean 'tutee'? Is that it?

Comment: @LesterNubla Is that a word??? ....that's what I came up with, but couldn't believe that it existed in real English....are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Oh yes it is a word. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tutee?s=t

Comment: @LesterNubla Wow, that is lame....are there any better-sounding alternatives? ....Thesaurus.com [didn't find any](http://thesaurus.com/browse/tutee)....

Comment: Haha. I can't think of another word. Let's just wait for some geek to answer your question. :)

Comment: @LesterNubla lol, let's :)

Comment: I have extensive experience with tutoring and running a tutoring center, and though I always rather disliked the word "tutee" it was what we always used for default of a better. And this from a guy who rejects the parallel formation "mentee" in favor of "Telemachus."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Why not make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @LesterNubla Same to you (see above comment)

Comment: @AnotherUser, I am just not feeling peckish for chicken heads just now.

Comment: I feel you @BrianDonovan ....this exchange can sometimes be far too militant for their own good :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single word for tutor-student is *[tutee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tutee)*

may be you can simply call it *student* or *pupil*.

Comment: Definitely just **student**!

Answer (score 2):

I've been tutoring for almost six years now.  I always refer to my "tutees" or "tutored-students" as simply "my student(s)".  SOMETIMES, there's confusion about whether or not I am a teacher (because I have "students"... therefore I must teach in a classroom) but more often than not, the context of the convo gives enough info for the person with whom I'm talking to to understand that ... no, I'm not a teacher.